# Symfony2 Ajax + Forms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I use Symfony 2.6 (I know, deprecated soon).
I want to create a web page that contains the same form 5 or 6 times (to create User) because one User can create limited numbers of others Users.
So I can't use FormBuilder because you can't display several times. Then I created normals HTML Forms:

```
 <form class="fcrv" action="{{ path('path') }}" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comm"></textarea> 
      <input type="submit" value="Validate">
 </form>
```

I Handle Form by Form with Ajax and I sent the data needed in my Controller. I can get data in Controller with :

```
$name = $request->request->get('Name');
$comm = $request->request->get('comm');
```

It's work.
After this I want to Simulate the behavior of a normal Form. I need to create my new Form and put the data in, so I did :

```
//create a new User
$user = new User();
$user->setCreateDate(new Date());

//Create the form
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
$form->setData(array('name'=>$name));
$form->setData(array('comm'=>$comm));

$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));

if ($form->isValid()) {
   //Some actions
}
```

---

My **UserType** :

```
<?php

 namespace Test\Bundle\Form;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

 class UserType extends AbstractType
 {
     /**
      * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
      * @param array $options
      */
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
     {
         $builder
             ->add('name', 'text')
             ->add('comm', 'text')
         ;
     }

     /**
      * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
      */
     public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
     {
         $resolver->setDefaults(array(
             'data_class' => 'Cfau\CleBundle\Entity\FraisVisite',
             'csrf_protection' => false
         ));
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getName()
     {
         return 'test_bundle_user';
     }
}
```

And the conditions in entity User is just : **@Assert\NotBlank()**

---

But the form isn't valid !

I disable CSRF token.

I use

```
 echo $form->getErrors(true, false);
```

to see what wrongs with my form and it say : **name: ERROR: This value should not be blank.** But I put data with **$form->setData(array('name'=>$name));** !

Can you help me.
Thanks !

Comment: Don't use setData. You can use handelRequest also when your form is not html form. But I don't understand why you can't render the same form twice ?

Comment: I don't know, I put my  {{ form_widget(form) }} in a Loop but he only display one time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, I think you should `setData` after `submit`, instead of before.

Also, be careful since you seem to use `"name"` in your FormBuilder but `"Name"` in your view (so maybe in your AJAX call as well). This might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. "Name" is a Syntax fault when I post on StackOverflow, my bad. I tried to setData after Submit but this didn't work too, I got the same errors.

Comment: Can you dump the content of `$request->request->get($form->getName())` and edit your question?